# getting an error trying to authenticate to firebase with google provider

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, create-react-app

here's my website code snippet :

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        app.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

also tried

```
signInWithPopup(provider)
```

both results the same (signInWithPopup shows popup which immediately closes).

I get the same console error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.Zb.he is not a function
    at Gg.toString (auth.js:136)
    at Mg (auth.js:141)
    at auth.js:140
    at e.Da (auth.js:39)
    at hd (auth.js:43)
    at dd (auth.js:43)
    at C.Zd (auth.js:42)
    at Oc (auth.js:36)
```

this used to work fine until few days ago.
tried different browsers , same result.

also tried rolling back firebase npm version to 6.6.4

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems weird. Are you using this in your reactjs app? Are you using the firebase.js CDN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it was due to our project structure.

We used 2 different firebase js package versions so probably obfuscation was different between the two.

solved with some webpack configurations.

Thanks.